# Chrome extension that communicates with multiple tabs, simultaneously

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am having trouble with making my chrome extension to work with multiple tabs, simultaneously.
The overall flow of my extension is:

Background script opens a new window at the beginning, where the extension js resides.

1. The extension than injects a js file in the browser's active tab, via `executeScript` api
2. In its callback sends a message to this same tab by which my js code performs operations on the tab's DOM
3. the active tab sends a message to the extension tab
4. the extension changes the address of the active tab, again via `executeScript`
5. background script listens to tabs.onUpdate to determine when the page address changed completed (status === 'complete'), to inject the js in the browser's active tab.

Steps 2-5 go on until a given criteria my extension tab UI defines is met, and the process stops.
This works fine, but I need to leverage this to happen in multiple tabs, simultaneously.

The first idea that pops is to create a number of tabs using `tabs.create` api, and assuming that simply passing the respective tab ids in the flow above - will work. But it does not.
In the simplest scenario of creating 2 tabs only, the 2 change address at the beginning - but the first tab only does that once. The process goes on with the 2nd tab only.

Is there an inherent problem with the flow above and the "infrastructure" of the extension that cannot accommodate such behavior ?
Am I missing using `web workers` in the background script - because it synchronize listening to multiple tabs messaging it ?

Any directions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear why you have to open an extension tab at all because normally you can do it in the background script. Without seeing the code it's unclear why scaling up is a problem because there are no inherent limitations in the extensions API. Web Workers shouldn't be relevant to the problem either.

Comment: The reason I open a tab for the extension is that I have several parameters that need to be determined at the beginning of the process. The parameters differ from site to site. I could indeed do it via background script, but the extension use is user based - someone has (intentionally) to manually trigger the process. I will paste a snippet with the simplest scenario as described above. I believe I tried it in the past few days, but will do it now and update here.

Comment: So the tab is like a dashboard and you want to find a good UI solution to scale it to multiple tabs. I guess I would implement it in one tab. It would have either sub-tabs or panels or cards that represent the controlled tabs.

Comment: that's basically what is happening right now (although very rudimentary) - the tabs are created in the extension UI. But at this very moment I managed to do it. I had a bug in my "context" synchronization object (the last tab was overwriting the data of the other tabs. I simply hold now a collection of contexts instead a single object - which was what I was doing.

Comment: I notice that if I scale the process to N tabs, as long as the tabs are "not visible"/not focused/not active (I do not think multiple tabs can be active at the same time...?) - the there is a lot of idle time between each tab address change. If I take all the tabs and make a new window for each, and resize them so I can leave ALL visible at the screen - each tab work happens way more frequently. Are you familiar with this ? Is there a remark somewhere in the API on that? In other words, scaling works poorly if all the tabs remain attached to the extension window. If I pop each of them out - ok

Comment: Chrome throttles and pauses inactive tabs. Some sites also reduce/pause their own activity by listening to `visibilitychange` event.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for that. Would make an answer by consolidating your comments above as "From what you describe, it should work, but one thing to keep in mind is..." so I can award you for the help?

Comment: I think it'd be better if you describe the most prominent points yourself.